# Nginx proxy + Node: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, pm2

I have a Node application with three endpoints.

In front I have an Nginx proxy balancing the requests to 5 instances of the application.

Nginx is setup to proxy three different domains to each of the three endpoints.

I'm dropping a lot of requests on Nginx with the errors:

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream
```

I'm running the Node applications with PM2. All error logs are empty and I can see from the uptime that the applications are not restarting or failing.

Here's my Nginx config:

```
upstream nodes {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:3000;
    ... 5 instances
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.service1.io;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://nodes/service1;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ... ssl config
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.service2.io;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://nodes/service2;
            ... same as above
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.service3.io;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://nodes/service3;
            ... same as above
    }
}
```

The services are running about 1 million requests/day but the application servers are not at all pushed.

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
    proxy_connect_timeout   60; #suite your need
    proxy_read_timeout      600; #suite your need
    proxy_send_timeout      600; #suite your need
```

maybe related to the timeout...